# Motherboard suddenly random stop when Intel i7 Turbo Boost enabled

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I'm using intel i7 4910MQ with embedded motherboard. On the detail specification it's use power supply adapter 12V, but when i activated Turbo BOOST on BIOS the cpu suddenly random stop & restarted. It's only work with turbo BOOST disabled and MAX Battery setting on BIOS

How can i know the problem is it cause by power supply need more 12V

Or any other problem such us the chipset HM87 is too hot, BIOS or something else ?

Here's link my motherboard
http://p.globalsources.com/IMAGES/PDT/SPEC/876/K1143127876.pdf

Comment: "How can i know the problem is it cause by power supply need more 12V" It's not possible to provide more then 12V to your system so this can't possibly be the problem

Answer (score 0):

You'll just have to methodically test everything (different settings & with different hardware) until you find out when it doesn't "stop," or find what makes it "stop" reliably.

And does "random stop" mean that the computer turns off suddenly, like the power cord was pulled out? That could be a bad power supply, try a different one & see what it does then.

Look for temp monitoring software too & see if things do get too hot. Even carefully checking with your finger would be better than nothing.

Comment: yes it turn off like power cord was pulled out. I did change the PSU which is power adapter with higher Watt but i see no different. The temp of CPU only below 70 deg Celsius with full usage. but may be the northbridge is higher i'm trying using fan & heatsink on it